# putting array of object in useEffect as dept

Tags: javascript, reactjs

says I have a users array of object coming from api, and I have this useEffect,

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(users.length) { // do something }
}, [users])
```

Is it more efficient to do this instead?

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(users.length) { // do something }
}, [users.length])
```

or it doesn't matter?

Comment: If you use `users.length` in dependency array, and if `users` has the value of `undefined`, then you will get the error. So its okay to go with the first approach and in the condition check you can do like `if(users && users.length)` .  First make sure `users` is not `undefined` and then check for length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can make a difference in performance, in the sense that you can reduce the amount of `useEffect` calls given the right conditions, so to answer it short: it depends...

***Disclaimer** I would actually not use the dependency array as a means to control performance, rather I would use it to control **when** the `useEffect` runs, given the requirements of my app, so my app behaves as I expect and how I want it to behave, and... well... gaining a small performance boost in the process as a nice side effect I guess.*

With that said, consider this example using `users` as a dependency. When pressing `Change values` the `useEffect` runs because `users` in general have changed, the same happens when changing the length (with `Change length` button):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.10.3/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel" data-presets="react,stage-3">
function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([1, 2, 3]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Don't display anything in the console on initial render
    if (users[0] === 1) return;
    console.log(users);
  }, [users]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick = {() => setUsers([2, 3, 4])}>Change values</button>
      <button onClick = {() => setUsers([2, 3, 4, 5])}>Change length</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
```

But, if you use `users.length` as a dependency the `useEffect` will only run when the length changes not when values change (try pressing the `Change values` button and see that *nothing happens* in the console because the length of the changed array is the same as the length in the initial state):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.10.3/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel" data-presets="react,stage-3">
function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([1, 2, 3]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Don't display anything in the console on initial render
    if (users[0] === 1) return;
    console.log(users);
  }, [users.length]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick = {() => setUsers([2, 3, 4])}>Change values</button>
      <button onClick = {() => setUsers([2, 3, 4, 5])}>Change length</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
```

So, to put it another way, you can control the amount of `useEffect` calls in your app by specifying the required dependency and ultimately make your app more performant, especially if you have a lot of logic in your `useEffect`.

Comment: make sense, so it's still fine to put array of object as deps, thanks!